# Trying to write to a Google Sheet opened with "openById"

Tags: google-sheets

Project description: Begin with a roster spreadsheet with multiple tabs (one for each group), each tab with a list of members for rows. Columns are rehearsal or program dates.  Second sheet contains scanned attendance records. Open the attendance record sheet and read each record. One column contains tab name of sheet on the roster sheet. Change to that sheet and search for the scanned member.  Mark the column matching the date with an X to denote attendance.  Mark the scanned attendance record with an X to denote processed.

Everything is working save the final writing of the X to the sheet opened by ID. I can't figure out the syntax to update the appropriate row/col cell.

I'd appreciate some help.  Thanks!

```
function processAttendanceRecords(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1234567");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rhrsDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][3], "PST", "M/d");
    sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName(data[i][1]));
    var members = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var col = members[0].indexOf(rhrsDate);
    for (var j = 1; j < members.length; j++) {
      if (data[i][6] == members[j][0] && data[i][7] == members[j][1]) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(j+1,col+1).setValue('X');
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(ss).getRange(i+1,9).setValue('X');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are accessing spreadsheet by ID then it is good practice to mention the sheet name or else it will take the first sheet by default.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123456").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```

Since you haven't defined the sheet name you can't use getRange(Row, Column). So your need to mention the sheet name like above and then change the last line.

```
ss.getRange(i+1,9).setValue('X');
```